# Is there a way to disable/change keyboard shortcuts in FireFox 57?

Tags: windows-10, firefox

Windows 10
FireFox

When I'm in a text field and press `CTRL` `B`, firefox opens the bookmark sidebar instead of passing the request to the site (SalesForce) to make my text bold. Is there a way to have the keyboard shortcut not apply when the focus is on a text field... or in a worst case scenario, just disable the keyboard shortcut all together?

I don't necessarily trust third-party add-ons and this seems like something I could configure in FireFox itself.

Comment: Try Alt-0002. The issue seems to be with the HTML in SalesForce: Hitting Ctrl-B in the SuperUser "Your Answer" edit box, below, correctly shows as bolded, but in this "Comment" edit box, it bring up Bookmarks.