# Workaround for changing hotkeys in Firefox Quantum

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-shortcuts, firefox-quantum

Currently there is no "supported way" to change the keyboard shortcuts for FF 57+ (see this [reddit.com post](https://www.reddit.com/r/firefox/comments/77gm9u/changing_default_keyboard_shortcuts_in_firefox_57/) for further information). I was wondering if anyone found/knows a good workaround to assign new keyboard shortcuts to Firefox Quantum ("overwriting" the existing shortcuts, if there are any), in my case for a Windows 7 system. Mainly I want to do the following:

- Open new Tab next to the current tab (Crtl+N)
- Open new Tab after the last tab (Alt+N)
- Close an existing tab (Crtl+X, if cut&paste for textselection keeps working, otherwise I want a different one)
- Open a new Window (Crtl+Shift+N)
- Close an existing window (Crtl+Shift+X, if cut&paste for textselection keeps working, otherwise I want a different one)
- and a few more, which I can list if required

My research so far:

The issue has been entered into the the [Mozilla bug report](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1215061#c66) and there is some [further info here](https://www.reddit.com/r/firefox/comments/7hjgbr/firefox_57_change_shortcut_keys/). And two questions in Mozilla's support forum [here](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1180599) and [here](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1209040). The articles talked about a few workarounds, but so far non of them worked for me.

Here are a few similar questions on the topic:

- [Change key bindings (keyboard shortcuts) in Firefox Quantum](https://superuser.com/questions/1271147/change-key-bindings-keyboard-shortcuts-in-firefox-quantum)
- [How to change Mozilla Firefox quit shortcut?](https://superuser.com/questions/943200/how-to-change-mozilla-firefox-quit-shortcut/1032014#1032014)
- [How to force to restart firefox in a clean way?](https://superuser.com/questions/992382/how-to-force-to-restart-firefox-in-a-clean-way/1358073#1358073)
- [Is there a way to disable/change keyboard shortcuts in FireFox 57?](https://superuser.com/questions/1272211/is-there-a-way-to-disable-change-keyboard-shortcuts-in-firefox-57)

Here are a few addons, which I couldn't get to work my way (maybe I did it wrong):

- https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/saka-key/
- https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/vimium-ff/?src=recommended
- https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/shortkeys/